# IntPtr to Event

Tags: c#, dllimport, handle

I'm using a function from a C++ dll that returns a handle to an event I need. I haven't worked with handles before, I'm having some trouble getting to the actual event. I'm importing it like this:

```
[DllImport("Some.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr eventCapturedCreate(int argument);
```

I haven't been successful with anything I tried past this point. My general approach has been using Marshal.PtrToStructure, but I'm not sure what type to specify.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't convert the event handle to a structure. It is an opaque value. The event handle is passed to other functions that receive the handle as an argument, such as `SetEvent`, `ResetEvent`, `WaitForSingleObject`, etc.

Keep track of the handle value in an `IntPtr` and pass that value to any other function that requires a handle to the event.

Comment: I'm not sure what I would pass this handle to. I'm writing C# and just trying to set up an event handler. Thanks!

Comment: Well I guess we are talking about different things. On Windows a handle to an event is a well defined thing. Nothing to do with event handlers.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am supposed to do with that link. You probably are in over your head.